# SQL Server table column with max value from group of entry. Access/SQL/Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a problem with SQL Server table design. I am making simple location database with app as a project data will be displayed in a Sharepoint site.

Here are my tables:

Phones

```
-----------------------------------------------
PhoneId | Model | MaxSpeed | DistanceTraveled |
   1    | Lumia | Problem1 |     Problem2     |
   2    | Lumia | Problem1 |     Problem2     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Locations

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LocationId | PhoneId | Long | Lat | Speed | Direction | DistanceFromLastLocation | 
     1     |    1    | data | dat |   3   |   data    |          Problem3        |         
     2     |    2    | data | dat |   4   |   data    |          Problem3        |
     3     |    2    | data | dat |   6   |   data    |          Problem3        |
     4     |    1    | data | dat |   5   |   data    |          Problem3        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And my questions are:

1. I want `MaxSpeed` to be max value from all location entries for given phone. I wrote a SQL query for selecting max value but I don't know how to refer to `PhoneId`. In my query access each time ask me for `PhoneId` - if you can tell me how to dynamic refer to `PhoneId` this would be awesome.
2. Similar problem I have no idea how to refer to `PhoneId` (for each Phone).
3. This column should be calculated based on value from previous entry (for given Phone).

Is this even possible in SQL or should I use macros?

My knowledge of SQL is limited but if you guys can point in right direction I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

For problems #1 and #2, use something like -

```
with [Maximums] (PhoneID, MaxSpeed, MaxDistanceTraveled)
(
    select
        PhoneID
        max(Speed) as [MaxSpeed],
        max(DistanceTraveled) as [MaxDistanceTraveled]
    from
        Locations
    group by
        PhoneID
    order by
        PhoneID asc
)
update
    Phones
set
    MaxSpeed = m.MaxSpeed,
    DistanceTraveled = m.MaxDistanceTraveled
from
    Phones as ph
        inner join
    Maximums as m
        on (ph.PhoneID = m.PhoneID)
```

**ALERT** - I did not test this so view it as a code template - Let me know if you have problems you can't resolve and post any error messages.

For problem #3 you need to provide more detail.  What exactly do you mean by "previous entry"?